# Reciting Shema in English

Tags: hebrew, shema, english

Is there any halachic requirement for the Shema to be recited in Hebrew only? I searched to make sure this was not a duplicate question and only found one that asks when reciting the Shema in English one should add Kel Melech Ne'eman when praying without a minyan. My question is simply about language only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Berachot 13a**](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=13&format=pdf)

> ת"ר ק"ש ככתבה דברי רבי וחכ"א בכל לשון מ"ט דרבי אמר קרא והיו בהוייתן
>   יהו ורבנן מאי טעמייהו אמר קרא שמע בכל לשון שאתה שומע ולרבי נמי הא כתיב
>   שמע ההוא מבעי ליה השמע לאזניך מה שאתה מוציא מפיך
>
> Our Rabbis taught: The Shema’ must be recited as it is written. So
>   Rabbi. The Sages, however, say that it may be recited in any language.
>   What is Rabbi's reason? — Scripture says: and they shall be, implying,
>   as they are they shall remain. What is the reason of the Rabbis? —
>   Scripture says ‘hear’, implying, in any language that you understand.
>   Rabbi also must see that ‘hear’ is written? — He requires it [for the
>   lesson]: Make your ear hear what your mouth utters. ([Soncino
>   translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

A few pages later, we find both disputants in another tannaic debate agreeing to the Sages' exposition that *Shema* can be recited in any language:

**[Berachot 15a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=15&format=pdf)**

> מאי טעמא דר' יוסי משום דכתיב שמע השמע לאזנך מה שאתה מוציא מפיך ות"ק
>   סבר שמע בכל לשון שאתה שומע ור' יוסי תרתי שמע מינה
>
> What is R. Jose's reason? — Because it is written, ‘Hear’ which
>   implies, let your ear hear what you utter with your mouth. The first
>   Tanna, however, maintains that ‘hear’ means, in any language that you
>   understand. But R. Jose derives both lessons from the word. ([Soncino
>   translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) rules like the Sages that Shema can be said in any language. However, he cautions that it must be said properly in that language:

**[Hilchot Keriat Shema 2:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=6&perek=2&halocha=10&hilite=)**

> קורא אדם את שמע בכל לשון שיהיה מבינה והקורא בכל לשון צריך להזהר מדברי
>   שבוש שבאותו הלשון ומדקדק באותו הלשון כמו שמדקדק בלשון הקדש
>
> A person may recite the Shema in any language he understands. One who
>   recites in a foreign language must be as scrupulous in his enunciation
>   as if he were reciting it in the Holy Tongue. ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/912953/jewish/Kriat-Shema-Chapter-Two.htm))

The other major codes of law rule accordingly:

**[Tur O.C. 62](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x165)**

> ונקראת בכל לשון דדרשינן שמע בכל לשון שאתה שומע וכתב הרמב"ם ז"ל הקורא
>   בכל לשון צריך ליזהר מדברי שיבוש שבאותו לשון וידקדק באותו לשון כמו
>   בלשון הקדש
>
> And it can be read in any language, for we expound "*shema*" [to mean] in
>   any language that you understand. And Rambam writes that one who reads
>   it in any language needs to be careful of the mistakes of that
>   language, and be precise in that language as in Hebrew.

**[Shulchan Aruch O.C. 62:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x432)**

> יכול לקרותה  בכל  לשון ויזהר מדברי שיבוש שבאותו לשון וידקדק בו כמו
>   בלשון הקודש
>
> One can read it in any language, and he should be careful of the
>   mistakes of that language.

**[Levush O.C. 62:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14586&st=&pgnum=50)**

> ויכול לקרותב בכל לשון דשמע פירושו הוא בכל לשון שאתה שומע ר"ל מבין רק
>   יזהר ג"כ מדברי שיבוש שבאותו לשון וידקדק בו כמו בלשון הקדש שאמרנו
>
> And one can read it in any language, because the meaning of "*shema*"
>   is any language that you can hear, i.e. understand. But one should
>   also be careful of the mistakes of that language, and be precise in it
>   as in Hebrew, as we have said.

**[Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 62:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=125&hilite=)**

> יכול לקרותה בכל לשון דכתיב שמע בכל לשון שאתה שומע ויזהר מדברי שיבוש
>   שבאותו לשון וידקדק בו כמו בלשון הקודש ודוקא כשמבין הלשון
>
> One can read it in any language, as it is written "*shema*" [which we
>   expound to mean] any language that you can hear. And one should be
>   careful of the mistakes of that language, and be precise in it as in
>   Hebrew. And this is only if he understands that language.

However, various later authorities have argued that nowadays one should not recite *Shema* in any other language because we don't know how to accurately translate it:

**[Aruch Hashulchan O.C. 62:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&st=&pgnum=126)**

> ודע דזה דק"ש ותפלה נאמרת בכל לשון ודאי זהו כשמעתיק ממש כל הג' פרשיות
>   וכל השמ"ע להלשון האחר דאל"כ אין זו ק"ש ותפלה ולפ"ז אין דין זה אלא בזמן
>   המשנה והגמרא שהיו יודעים בטוב לשונינו והיו יכולים להעתיקו אבל עכשיו
>   ידוע שכמה ספיקות יש לנו בפירוש המלות ונחלקו בו המפרשים
>
> And know that this that *Keriat Shema* and prayer can be said in any
>   language is certainly [only] when all three chapters and all 18
>   blessings are exactly translated into the other language. For if it is
>   not done so then it's not [actually] *Keriat Shema* or prayer. And
>   according to this, this law is only [applicable] in the times of the
>   *Mishnah* and the *Gemara* when they knew well our language and were able to translate it. But now it is known that we have many
>   uncertainties in the meaning of the words, and the commentaries are in
>   dispute over [the meanings].

**[Mishnah Berurah 62:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49623&st=&pgnum=188)**

> ועיין בספרי האחרונים דבימינו אף מצד הדין יש ליזהר שלא לקרותה בלשון אחר
>   כ"א בלשון הקודש כי יש כמה וכמה תיבות שאין אנו יודעים איך להעתיקם היטב
>
> And look in the books of the later authorities, that in our day even
>   according to the actual law one should be careful to not read it in
>   another language other than Hebrew, because there are many words which
>   we don't know how to translate properly.

Answer (score 5):

[Mishna Sotah 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Sotah.7):1

> אֵלּוּ נֶאֱמָרִין בְּכָל לָשׁוֹן, פָּרָשַׁת סוֹטָה, וּוִדּוּי מַעֲשֵׂר, קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע, וּתְפִלָּה, וּבִרְכַּת הַמָּזוֹן, וּשְׁבוּעַת הָעֵדוּת, וּשְׁבוּעַת הַפִּקָּדוֹן:
>
> The following are said in any language: the paragraph of Sotah (Numbers 5:19-22), declaration of tithes (Deuteronomy 26:13), the recitation of Shema (Deuteronomy 6:4-9), prayer, the blessing after a meal, the oath of testimony, and the oath of a deposit.

One would probably still want to use Hebrew if one can for any of a number of reasons (eg. tradition, mystical significance of the Hebrew language, difficulty in finding a completely accurate translation) but in principle saying it in English, at least if one understands English, is valid.

Answer (score 5):

There is a beginner's guide to Shema on the [aish.com website](http://www.aish.com/jl/m/pb/48954656.html) where it says:

> The important thing is to understand and concentrate on the meaning of
>   the words. If you don't understand Hebrew, you can say it in English
>   as well. And then make it a goal to learn the pronunciation and
>   meaning to be able to say it in Hebrew as well.

There is a long article on this question [here](http://din.org.il/2018/06/29/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2-%D7%91%D7%9B%D7%9C-%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F/) .

Key points are:

> 1] הרמב”ם (הלכות קריאת שמע, פרק ב, הלכה י) פוסק כדעת חכמים, ומוסיף פרט
>   חשוב: “קורא אדם את שמע בכל לשון שיהיה מבינה, והקורא בכל לשון צריך
>   להיזהר מדברי שיבוש שבאותו הלשון, ומדקדק באותו הלשון כמו שמדקדק בלשון
>   הקודש”. לדעת הרמב”ם, צריך אדם לדקדק בקריאת שמע בלעז, כמו שמדקדק בתיבות
>   של לשון הקודש. הראב”ד משיג על דבריו אלו: “אין זה מקובל על הדעת, לפי
>   שכל הלשונות פירוש הן, ומי ידקדק אחר פירושו”.
>
> 1] Rambam allows Shema in a language you understand, pronounced
>   accurately. The Raavad disagrees because an accurate translation is
>   impossible.
>
> 2] המשנה ברורה (סימן סב, ס”ק ג) פוסק שיש להימנע מקריאת שמע בשאר לשונות
>   בזמן הזה, ומעורר שמא אין לקרוא בלעז בזמן הזה מעיקר הדין: “ועיין בספרי
>   האחרונים דבימינו אף מצד הדין יש ליזהר שלא לקרותה בלשון אחר, כי אם
>   בלשון הקודש, כי יש כמה וכמה תיבות שאין אנו יודעים איך להעתיקם היטב,
>   כגון תיבת ושננתם יש בו כמה ביאורים, אחד לשון לימוד ואחד לשון חידוד,
>   כמו שאמרו חז”ל ‘שיהו ד”ת מחודדין בפיך, שאם ישאלך אדם דבר אל תגמגם
>   ותאמר לו’. וכן כמה וכמה תיבות שבקריאת שמע שאין אנו יודעין היטב ביאורו
>   על לשון אחר, כגון תיבת ‘את’ ותיבת ‘לטוטפות’, וכדומה”.
>
> 2] Mishnah Berurah advises against reciting shema other than in
>   Hebrew. There are words in it with mutiple translations and words
>   without a definite translation.
>
> 3] From the Yerushalmi, some bring the law that if one can read the
>   shema in Hebrew one will not perform the mitzvah if it is done in any
>   other language.