# Accepting a fast upon oneself after the prayer of Mincha

Tags: fast-days, mincha-afternoon-prayer

If someone wants to do a personal fast (taanit) and forgot to receive it during Mincha. Can he still receive it after Mincha before the day is out? What should he recite?

Answer (score 2):

The Mishnah Beruruah ([תקסג](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.563?lang=he)) says that after Mincha [בדיעבד] as long as it is still day he can still accept the fast, verbally and mentally.

> אלא קודם לזה דאלו אחר שהתפלל משמע מאחרונים דמהני הקבלה **בדיעבד** כל
>   זמן שהוא יום בין בהוצאה בפה ובין בהרהור:

As for an acceptable acceptance-text, you could say something [like](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.562?lang=he):

> הריני בתענית יחיד מחר יהי רצון שתהא תפלתי ביום תעניתי מקובלת

Or [even](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.562.29?lang=he):

> הריני בתענית מחר

And probably even a [native-equivalent.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96026/16706)